# In fortran, can I type function?

Tags: fortran

I want make a function as I type and read it as a function. For example, if I type x+y, then f(x,y)=x+y. Is this possible? The following code does not work.

```
real function f(x,y)
real x,y
write(6,*) "type f(x,y)"
read*, f
return
end
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7326828/passing-strings-for-execution-in-fortran-subroutines

Comment: "does not work" is not very helpful. Also, you seem to have forgotten a closing quote.

Comment: @DaveP Edited the typo. Coding is okay but if I run the program, it stops and does not give any message. If I delete the 3rd line and type "x+y", then it gives an error message that what I typed is not real.

Comment: Should `f` be ignoring the `x` and `y` passed to it?

Comment: I do not think that this is possible.

Comment: My approach would be, to include an interpreted language, which can do this. I think Python would be a good choice... But don't ask me, how to do this.

Comment: The real gist of the question is: "I want to write a parser in Fortran, but I don't know what a parser is." Please learn more about parsers and compilers (Aho, Ullman is your first stop) and come back with more specific questions. Fortran is not a language well suited for coding parsers in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can, but your syntax is a bit off.

```
      PROGRAM READFUNC
        REAL x,y,F,res

        res = F(x,y)

        WRITE(*,*) res
      END

      REAL FUNCTION F(x,y)
        REAL x,y

        WRITE (*,*) "Type in"
        READ (*,*) F

        RETURN
      END
```

note that I compiled this w/ gfortran so I'm not sure if it uses any F90+ extensions or not.

**EDIT** After reading your edits, I see that this isn't what you want; you want some kind of eval/parser.  In general this is not a trivial thing.  You're going to have to do some kind of token parsing work.

However there are libraries that can do this for you that are already written.

See [this article](http://gbenthien.net/strings/evaluate.pdf) for an example of where to look for more research.

Comment: I tested this program. Coding is okay, but it has no response after I run it.

Comment: What compiler are you using?

Comment: Isn't that a recursive write? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7646278/function-call-stopping-hanging-when-containing-a-write-statement-but-only-when

Comment: @Deditos It probably is; my lack of access to non-gfortran compilers betrays me.  If you separate out the function call into an assignment and then a write then it should be non-recursive.

Comment: This is not recursion. Inside function f() f is a real variable and the above works just fine if the user keys in the *number* to be returned by the function.

Answer (score 0):

```
     F(X,Y)=X+Y
 99  READ(*,*)X,Y
     WRITE(*,*)F(X,Y)
     GO TO 99
```

You enter 3  4    or 3,4  and you get out 7