# Fortran program freezes if a call to MPI_Initialized is present

Tags: fortran, gfortran, mpich

The following Fortran program freezes on call to `print_test`.

```
program test_prg
  implicit none
  integer :: mpi_enabled, ierr

  call MPI_Initialized(mpi_enabled, ierr)
  print *, print_test()

contains

  function print_test() result(res)
    real :: res 
    res = 0 
    print *, 'HELLO'
  end function
end program
```

The call to `print_test` can even be before the call to `MPI_Initialized` and still freeze as long as the call to `MPI_Initialized` and `print *, print_test()` is present somewhere in the program. The same problem can also be reproduced if `MPI_Initialized` is replaced with `MPI_Init`, but not if I remove it. If I remove `print *, 'HELLO'`, then it works. If I call `print_test` on a separate line and then print the result, then it works. The problem is observed when compiled with `gfortran` 9.3.0 (through `mpifort`). The same program works without issues when compiled with `ifort`. MPICH version is 3.3.2.

Is this a `gfortran` bug? Does anyone know how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 2):

It was pointed out to me that the issue has to do with recursive IO, which is apparently not permitted by the standard. In short, if a function prints to a unit, it cannot be called in IO list of a print statement associated with the same unit. One has to assign the return value of the function to a variable and then print the variable, or print to another unit. It's rather unfortunate that failure to comply with this rule results in runtime freeze with no explanation, instead of a compile-time error. The exact same questions have already been asked and answered, see for example:

[Function call stopping/hanging when containing a write-statement, but only when linking with certain libraries during compilation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7646278/function-call-stopping-hanging-when-containing-a-write-statement-but-only-when/7662569)

and

[Print to standard output from a function defined in an Fortran module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24923076/print-to-standard-output-from-a-function-defined-in-an-fortran-module)

Comment: A compile time error would be difficult as the problem has only occurred because the function was invoked from within an I/O statement, and when the function is being compiled the compiler may not be able to determine that this is the case, and similarly when the line invoking the function is compiled the compiler may not be able to determine that the function contains an I/O statement. This situation is all but unavoidable in the case of external functions.